# Elasticsearch Term Filter on Array

Tags: arrays, search, filter, elasticsearch

I'm having trouble getting the Terms filter working for for an index.

Right now I'm searching:

```
"term" : { "tags" : "Dining"}
```

*EDIT: assume that the query filters are in the right place as well, just pulling this from part of a script.*

Assume that the `tags` item is an array of different tags a document may have. What I expected to result would be a list of documents with the tag "Dining". What actually happened is a result with 0 documents.

For mappings, it looks like this:

```
'tags' => [
    'type' => 'string',
    'index' => 'not_analyzed',
]
```

Is there a certain mappings I have to have on the array to make the Term Filter match it? Something wrong with the Term filter? I'm thinking I should change it to the Terms filter vs Term. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized that since I remapped it, it has since been working with the **Terms** filter, not the Term filter.